# Keep hover style on parent when hovering over a tooltip that is NOT a descendant

Tags: css, hover, html

I have a "parent" div that contains an element with a tooltip control. The tooltip is not child element of the parent div and is attached directly to the body element. We have a style when hovering over the parent which is lost when hovering over the tooltip. Is there a CSS-based solution for keeping the hover style on the parent while hovering over the tooltip that is not a descendant of the parent?

Comment: you could also apply the hover effect to tooltip?

Comment: can you create a [mcve] showing your current html layout and css for the parent hover to show the tooltip

Answer (score 1):

Just change this:

```
#parent:hover {
    /*show tooltip*/
}
```

To this:

```
#parent:hover, #tooltip:hover {
    /*show tooltip*/
}
```